# How to write GHunit test cases for delegate Methods?

Tags: objective-c, gh-unit

Can we write GHunit test for delegate methods ?  I have a delegate method and I am trying to write GHUnit Test for that delegate methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on how you want to test the delegate method.  If you want to test that a delegate method **was called** in a certain scenario, then you can use mock objects for that.  [OCMock](http://ocmock.org) is the typical framework on iOS and Mac OS for mocking.  The last time I checked it played nicely with GHUnit.  I'm using SenTest exclusively now, so I cannot say authoritatively.

If you want to test the **functionality** of a delegate method, nothing prevents you from calling the delegate method directly from within the test case.